# Would protons in a straight line ever break their alignment?

Tags: forces, protons, thought-experiment

Let any amount of arbitrarily spaced protons appear along a line segment of length $x$ in an otherwise empty universe at $t+0$

What mechanism, if any, could cause the breaking of said alignment between $t+\large\frac{x}{c}$ & $t+\small\infty$?

Comment: The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle will make that difficult.

Comment: If you allow quantum effects, then the uncertainty principle.

Comment: What's the point of your question?

Comment: Wouldn't knowing that the position of each proton is still in the exact alinement after they each had an initial effect on each other negate any uncertainty about their velocity ? Otherwise the alinement would've been broken before  $t+\large\frac{x}{c}$

Comment: Photons travel as waves (see diffraction), don't have a position until absorbed, and don't have an effect on each other. Your question seems to present photons as little balls, which is incorrect.

Comment: @safesphere The question is about **protons**, not photons. True, they aren't little balls either.

Comment: Forcing the protons onto the line will necessarily increase the uncertainty in their momenta, which will tend to move them randomly away from the line.

Comment: @BillN I'd like to know whether protons behave as point-like particles in this scenario

Comment: @PM2Ring Where are my reeding glasses? Well, protons do affect each other, but still travel as waves with diffraction and no position until detected. Not little balls either.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm not asking about the feasability, it's a thought experiment, that is why I said the protons "appear". I'm not asking about the uncertainty of the measurement either, I specifically said that they **are** alined, I didn't say I measured them. You either didn't understand the question or you really mean that the quantum theory holds as law that protons are forbidden from staying perfectly alined

Comment: If a proton has very small uncertainty in its position, then it must have large uncertainty in its momentum. That's an inevitable mathematical consequence of the fact that a particle's position & momentum functions are related by the Fourier transform.

Comment: The uncertainty principle says we cannot **measure** position and momentum precisely at the same time. So this principle applies at the point of detection. However, while in flight, particles travel as waves with no position at all. A position in flight is not just uncertain, it doesn't exist as a concept. Waves don't have a position.

Comment: don't forget the magnetic moment.

Comment: Given that they can stay in that line for x amount of time, how can you still say for sure that them staying in line for any amount of time doesn't mean the system is configured in such a way that its variables cannot end in anything but a straight line ?

Comment: The only meaningful definitions of particles "aligned" would be them having the same wave function. The wave would still experience diffraction, so a perfect classical alignment is not possible. For example (not protons, but still), a laser beam is much more "aligned" than a flashlight beam, but still diffracts.

Comment: Oh alright so it's a law then, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question assumes infinitely perfect alignment and exactly zero initial motion of the protons.

Quantum mechanics contradicts both of those assumptions. For all particles there is an inherent minimum uncertainty in position, and a minimum uncertainty in momentum. The more precisely you try to define one, the greater the uncertainty in the other. If you try to define the positions precisely, they are going to have large and random momentums throwing them out of alignment. If you try to get them motionless, the positions will contain significant randomness.

So the answer is that the laws of physics do not allow you to create a perfect alignment in the first place. In fact quantum mechanics says the alignment can't exist at all. The positions and momentum values don't exist - over time they have probabilistic values. Sooner or later a random fluctuation will cause an imbalanced force, which inevitably causes a cascading failure of any unstable arrangement.